# Installing PDO driver for MySQL on windows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using quickphp to process my php file with was previously processed using wamp server. I also installed mysql for the database. I am using pdo with was working fine on wamp but i get this error while trying to access the site now.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in C:\Users***\Documents***\includes\database.php:3 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users***\Documents***\includes\database.php(3): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', 'root') #1 C:\Users***\Documents***\menu.php(7): require('C:\Users\selfse...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\Users***\Documents***\includes\database.php on line 3

How can i install pdo driver for mysql. I have searched the net but still clueless.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php

Comment: Why are you trying to use QuickPHP over Wamp? What is the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

It's a common problem, and one I've solved for a few people recently. Make sure you check the following list to ensure you have put them in place:

Ensure both php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll and php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll are in
    your /ext directory. Ensure the following lines are present in your
    php.ini file: extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.
   dll & extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll. 
   Ensure you have installed VC++ redist located [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679). Make sure you download and install the x86
    version regardless of the architecture of your OS otherwise this
    will not work.

Check these things and come back to me with an answer.